# getElementById not returning element

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to get an elements id from another elements value and I just keeps returning null. Clicking on the first check box should show what the issue is that I am having.

```
<input id="test" type="checkbox" name="checkAddress" onclick="checkAddress(this)" value="66" />
<input id="rrrr66" type="checkbox" name="checkAddress" onclick="checkAddress(this)" value="33" />
<script>
    function checkAddress(checkbox) {
        if (checkbox.checked) { 
            var testing = '"rrrr'+document.getElementById("test").value+'"';
        alert(typeof testing); **<-- shows the correct type**
        alert(testing); **<-- shows the correct value**
        alert(document.getElementById(testing)); **<-- does not work**
        alert(document.getElementById("rrrr66")); **<--works**
        }
    }
```

[Demo Of issue](http://jsfiddle.net/c8y4bgmL/3/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the quotation marks from the string:

```
var testing = 'rrrr'+document.getElementById("test").value;
```

Quotation marks are for the **parser** to indicate a *string literal*. The quotation marks are not actually part of the value. What you are currently doing is equivalent with

```
document.getElementById('"rrrr66"')
```

Compare these two outputs:

```
console.log("foo bar"); // foo bar
console.log('"foo' + ' bar"'); // "foo bar"
```

Answer (score 0):

### 1

Get the value of `test` and add *rrrr* before:

```
var testing = "rrrr"+document.getElementById("test").value;
```

### 2 Do the trick

```
document.getElementById(testing)
```

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/c8y4bgmL/10/) should work.

Comment: There a two elements, one has ID `rrrr66`.

Comment: Yes, but you're trying to `document.getElementById(testing)`, when **testing** var is equal to `'"rrrr'+document.getElementById("test").value+'"';`, this is like `document.getElementById('"rrrr'+document.getElementById("test").value+'"')`.

Comment: I'm not doing anything. But yes, that is the problem (I guess, not sure what exactly you are referring to), not that there is an element with ID `test`. Btw, your answer doesn't really include any information. What solution are you proposing?